# New Xamarin.Forms solution using the template failing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a new Xamarin.Forms solution by selecting: File > New Solutions > Forms App using .Net standard library.

As soon as I rebuild without making any code changes I see the following errors:

```
namespace test3.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "test3", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

> protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)

```
Green line under bundle with this message: parameter name differs in base declaration
```

> TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
>   ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

```
Red line under Tabbar with this message: Ambiguity between Resource.Layout.Tabbar and Resource.Layout.Tabbar
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?  Hoping for some advice.

Note if it's any help there appear to be two versions of Resource:

```
..test3.Android/Resources/Resource.designer.cs
..test3.Android/obj/debug/designtime/Resoure.designer.cs
```

as for the override being different I am not sure what is causing that problem

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> parameter name differs in base declaration

The project template is just mismatched on the parameter name, it does not cause any compile/runtime issue, just a pain to see in the editor. You can change the name to `savedInstanceState` match to make Intellisense happy.

> Ambiguity between Resource.Layout.Tabbar and Resource.Lay.....

The ambiguity issue is a bug in how the generated file is applied to the Roslyn-based Intellisense system. Long-time known issue that has been fixed and re-broken multiple times across different releases. While is it is a pain to see the red Intellisense line, the project will compile/run fine...

Comment: Thanks very much for your help on this !  Accepting now